# Cannot access application that deployed in Apache Http Server + Tomcat + SSL architecture with Firefox or Chrome browers

Tags: apache, tomcat, https

Our application deployment architecture is `Apache HTTP Server` + `Tomca`t + `SSL`(I use go-daddy.com SSL certificate), now I can access successfully the application with URL https://remote.com:23/project by IE browser only, it cannot be accessed by Chorme or Firefox with the same URL. I guess it may be caused by a unauthentic SSL certificate I used.

Comment: Its not accessible from IE too

Comment: This is not a real IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl` (in verbose mode) and `sslscan` to see what is actually advertised by the server.